# ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open

Tags: sql, vb.net, connection

I am currently getting the Error:

> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.

Here is my code:

Class for db.conn

```
Public Class db
    Public Shared conn As SqlConnection = db.getsqlconn("ezondb")



    Public Shared Function getsqlconn(ByVal whichdb As String) As SqlConnection
        Dim connstring As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(whichdb).ConnectionString
        Return New SqlConnection(connstring)
    End Function



Dim Macomm = db.selectcommand(db.conn, "*", "categories", "idparentcategory=1")
Dim Mada As New SqlDataAdapter(Macomm)
Dim Mat As New DataTable
Mada.Fill(Mat)
```

Comment: Please show us more code. Where do you open the connection?

Comment: I have added more code.

Comment: In the code you show the connection is not opened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would not declare connections as `Shared`:

```
Public Shared conn As SqlConnection = db.getsqlconn("ezondb")
```

Open a connection when you need it, and close it right after.

Answer (score -1):

The getsqlconn method is just returning a new instance of sqlconnection object, you need to explicitly open the connection by calling the open method

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm switching from php to .net. This is fairly new to me.